# Custom Setting providing NULL value

Tags: apex, customsetting

I created a Custom Setting to store an Id so I do not have to hard-code it. The custom setting API name is `SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID__c` and is of type 'Hierarchy'. It has 1 field called `Squad Picklist ID`  (api name `Squad_Picklist_ID__c`) and is of type text(50). I have set the default value of that field to the Id.

When I use:

`SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID__c SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID = SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID__c.getInstance('Squad Picklist ID');` I get the error `System.InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid SetupOwner for Custom Settings: Squad Picklist ID`

When I use: `SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID__c SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID = SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID__c.getOrgDefaults();` I do not get any errors, but the value returned is `{ }`.

When I use:

`SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID__c SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID = SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID__c.getValues('Squad Picklist ID');` I get the error `Invalid SetupOwner for Custom Settings: Squad Picklist ID`

Finally, when I run the SOQL Query `select Id from SQUAD_GLOBAL_VALUE_SET_ID__c` I do not get an error, but it says 'No rows returned' which is strange. I have Googled and tried lots of solutions but nothing works. I think I may have set up the custom setting incorrectly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you read up on **[Custom Settings Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm)**. It covers what you need to understand here in detail.

Hierarchy Custom Settings do not work the way you are trying to use them. You get an instance for the `Organization`, a `Profile`, or a specific `User`. You pass in an Id for any of these values to `getInstance`, or you can call `My_Setting__c.getOrgDefaults()`.

```
My_Setting__c orgDefault = My_Setting__c.getOrgDefaults();
My_Setting__c myProfileSetting = My_Setting__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getProfileId());
My_Setting__c myUserSetting = My_Setting__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getUserId());
```

Comment: Thank you. I used a custom metadata type instead and it works now