# Invalid Set up owner for custom settings

Tags: customsetting, custom-controller

I am trying to retrieve a custom setting that I made with this code:

```
    public static String getCustomKey(){
        AP_Mobile_Key__c APMobileKey = AP_Mobile_Key__c.getInstance('AP Mobile Key');
        String myCCVal = APMobileKey.Key__c;
        if(APMobileKey != null){
          System.debug(myCCVal);
          return myCCVal;
        }
        return 'No key';
    }
```

When I try to run it, i get error: `Invalid SetupOwner for Custom Settings: AP Mobile Key`

These settings exist, I just created them. I cant see to find any reference to this error using Google.

Comment: Can you confirm that the custom settings is of type Hierarchy ? if yes, do check the answer on this existing post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233827/custom-setting-providing-null-value

Comment: @Shamina Changing it to `list` type removes the error but now its null when I do:
`AP_Mobile_Key__c APMobileKey = AP_Mobile_Key__c.getInstance('AP Mobile Key');` Even though these settings are present.

Comment: Are you sure the value 'AP Mobile Key' matches exactly the "Name" field value in your custom settings? also check if the value 'AP Mobile Key' is correct and there are no spaces in between the actual value in the custom setting

Comment: I never add any data to it it's fixed thanks

Comment: Alright. Can you mark my answer below as acceptable then; I have posted a formal answer to recap on how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to recap how this was fixed:

The error "Invalid SetupOwner for Custom Settings: AP Mobile Key" was due to the custom settings being hierarchical and `getinstance` was being used incorrectly on Name value, instead of organisation, user or profile id (Refer to more detailed answer in similar question here: [Custom Setting providing NULL value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233827/custom-setting-providing-null-value))

(If applicable) When changing the custom settings into List type, ensure that call to `getinstance` method is based on Name value, and that this has corresponding record data